# Extending Swing's ToolTipManager to change behaviour on hover?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tooltip, custom-component

I'd like to implement a ToolTip in Swing that has customised behaviour: the longer the user hovers over the component, the more detail should be shown in the tooltip (i.e., a few new lines are added after a few seconds of the user hovering over the component). I just need to check whether this is really doable with Swing without things getting too messy. My idea at the moment would probably be:

- Extend ToolTipManager
- Override mouseEntered to start a timer (maybe use javax.swing.Timer?). Call setToolTipText and createToolTip to refresh the tooltip and add new information at regular intervals
- Override mouseExited to reset the timer
- Probably use setDismissDelay to set the dismiss delay to something a lot longer (or Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Is such a thing feasible or is this not a good way to work with Swing (sorry, I'm pretty new to it)? Is there a better way of doing this?

[edit] Hmm, just remembered that ToolTipManager is a singleton with a constructor that only has package visibility, so it can't be extended.

[edit 2] I'm trying out a few solutions at the moment. One thing that I forgot to add is that I do need to know which component is being hovered over - which I guess means I'll need to be working with some sort of listener with a mouseEntered() method (or be able to access this information). And no other interactivity with the popup/tooltip is needed - it just needs to display information.

Comment: "*Is such a thing feasible?*" Yes.  Your way looks like a good option, but without a concrete implementation it's hard to tell..

Comment: True! If it sounds like a decent option I'll give it a go - probably the best way of finding out.

Comment: With some more info I could guide you a bit more. Would something like "for every additional X seconds of hovering, add another line to the tooltip text" be a good example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I just realised though that ToolTipManager is a singleton and can't be extended - makes things more complicated.

Comment: I was actually constantly thinking about `JToolTip` instead of `ToolTipManager` when reading the question (oops). The former is the one you can override, but I think that there's a simpler way.with overriding `getToolTipText(MouseEvent event)` for the component.

Comment: Oh great, glad there's another option. I'd gotten the two mixed up - that sounds like it'll work.

Comment: I got partial success via cheating. I think that overriding `JToolTip` is only necessary if you need something complicated. Is it working for you? Try to post some attempt in the question.

Comment: @false_azure JWindow/undecorated JDialog if some type of motality is there required (thats required:-)

Comment: @false_azure JPopup is very good also, maybe excelent, better than JWindow/JDialog because flow away on (methods in API) 1st. mouse/key event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This may seem a bit confusing so let me know if you need me to clarify let me know and I'll try to show you how I picture the code) I think your idea might work like if you extend it, and also make a private class that extends `Thread`and then in the `run()` method you do something like

```
while(true)
{
    sleep(1);
    timeElapsed++;
}
```

And in your class that extends `ToolTipManager`, create a field for that class that extends `Thread` and in the `mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)` instantiate the thing like:

```
extendsThreadClass = new ExtendsThreadClass();
extendsThreadClass.start();
```

and then in the `mouseExited(MouseEvent e)` method do

`extendsThreadClass = null;`

Then in that `mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)` method after starting the `Thread`  then you can do what you want to do after the time thing like

```
if(timeElapsed > 3000)
{
   //what you want to do here
}
```

Sorry it may be confusing, let me know if i can clear it up for you

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should update this with the approach I took before I saw l1zZY's answer (which I think is the better way of doing things - I still had bugs in my code before I moved onto something else, but this might still be helpful to someone). This is what I did:

- Extend JToolTip
- Use a Swing Timer for timing
- Add a MouseMotion listener to the JTree (in my case I wanted the popup to show when a node was hovered over)
- Somewhat inelegantly, detect when the mouse moved over a tree node like this:

  ```
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
  int x = (int) e.getX();
  int y = (int) e.getY();
  TreePath path = getPathForLocation(x, y);
  if (path == null) {
      tooltip.hide();
  } else {
      TreeNode node = (TreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
      tooltip.setHoveredNode(node); 
      if (!tooltip.isVisible) {
          int absX = e.getXOnScreen();
          int absY = e.getYOnScreen();
          final Popup tooltipContainer = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(PDTreeView.this, 
                  tooltip, absX, absY);
          tooltip.setToolTipContainer(tooltipContainer);
          tooltip.show();
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- `tooltip.show()` refers to how the tooltip was contained in a Popup
  in order to show or hide it programmatically. `show()` shows the
  Popup (and therefore tooltip) and also starts the Swing timer.
- Timer has a method called `actionPerformed()` which is called at whatever interval you set. I just had that method call the code that adds new information to the tooltip. in `hide()`, I reset the tooltip and the timer.

I had issues with the popup or tooltip not resizing to fit the content, but otherwise this seemed ok.